# What is the default TCP window size scaling value in Android and in iOS

Tags: android, ios, tcp

What is the default TCP window size scaling value for both Android and iOS?

Comment: Window? What window?

Comment: @greenapps By "TCP Window size scaling value" I mean the option defined in RFC 1323 as **"an implicit scale factor, which is used to multiply the window size value found in a TCP header to obtain the true window size."**